# Form builder 'Cannot read property (...) of null'

Tags: angular, formbuilder, angular2-formbuilder

**Model.ts**

```
class A {
    b: B;
}

class B {
    someValue: string;
}
```

**Component.ts**

```js
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

this.formInput = this.formBuilder.group({
    'valueController': [this.a.b.someValue],
});
```

**Error**

When loading the page for the first time the following error shows:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'someValue' of null
```

I'm building a form page to create an entity, where the model starts out empty. I've tried initializing `b` in the constructor, but it doesn't work. I don't want to set the value of `b` in the `component.ts`

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daniel, I suppose you has some like

```
this.a=new A()
```

But a is only an empy object , it's like you write

```
this.a={}
```

If your class has a constructor like

```
class A {
    b: B;
    constructor()
    {
      this.b=new B()
    }
}

this.a will be an object with property b, but this.a.b is an empty object too.
```

Only if you write in constructor of B, some like

```
class B {
    someValue: string;
    constructor()
    {
      this.someValue="hello"
    }
}
```

You'll get an object with value

NOTE: Usually in Angular we use interface if the only aim is has "typed variables", you can see the docs [about class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) or [about interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)